# Can we intercept JavaScript in Webview?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am loading external website into the `webview`. On one of its pages, there is a button which shows/hides table. The show/hide action is done via `JavaScript`.

I have not been able to detect this `JavaScript` no matter which method I override in `WebChromeClient`. I can detect `JavaScript` alert popups, but not this code.

I basically want to know when a user has shown this table to I can offer him additional help filling the table.

Can this be done at all?

Comment: Have you try [onLoadResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onLoadResource%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)?